# Received an invalid_authentication error when querying a Foursquare venue

Tags: foursquare

> I am trying to query for details of venues using the Foursquare venues
>   API, but i received a "invalid_auth" error

```
VENUE_ID='54ea41ad498e9a11e9e13308'
VERSION = '20190823'

venueurl = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(VENUE_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION)

venueresults = requests.get(venueurl).json()
venueresults
```

> This is the error i received.
>
> {'meta': {'code': 400,   'errorType': 'invalid_auth',   'errorDetail':
>   'Missing access credentials. See
>   https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication
>   for details.',   'requestId': '5d613b698afbe000358acf53'}, 
>   'response': {}}
>
> I expect to receive a response as shown below (shortened as the
>   response is too long.

https://foursquare.com/developers/explore#req=venues%2F54ea41ad498e9a11e9e13308

> { "meta": { "code": 200 "requestId": "5d613941075a420023f41750" }
>   "notifications": [ { "type": "notificationTray" "item": {
>   "unreadCount": 0 } } ] "response": { "venue": { "id":
>   "54ea41ad498e9a11e9e13308" "name": "Roselle Desserts" "contact": {
>   "phone": "+14163688188" "formattedPhone": "+1 416-368-8188" "twitter":
>   "roselle_to" } "location": { "address": "362 King St E" "crossStreet":
>   "Trinity St" "lat": 43.653446723052674 "lng": -79.3620167174383
>   "labeledLatLngs": [ { "label": "display" "lat": 43.653446723052674
>   "lng": -79.3620167174383 } ] "postalCode": "M5A 1K9" "cc": "CA"
>   "city": "Toronto" "state": "ON" "country": "Canada"
>   "formattedAddress": [ "362 King St E (Trinity St)" "Toronto ON M5A
>   1K9" "Canada" ] } "canonicalUrl":
>   "https://foursquare.com/v/roselle-desserts/54ea41ad498e9a11e9e13308"
>   "categories": [ { "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d16a941735" "name": "Bakery"
>   "pluralName": "Bakeries" "shortName": "Bakery" "icon": { "prefix":
>   "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/bakery_" "suffix": ".png"
>   } "primary": true } { "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1d0941735" "name":
>   "Dessert Shop" "pluralName": "Dessert Shops" "shortName": "Desserts"
>   "icon": { "prefix":
>   "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/dessert_" "suffix":
>   ".png" } } { "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1c9941735" "name": "Ice Cream Shop"
>   "pluralName": "Ice Cream Shops" "shortName": "Ice Cream" "icon": {
>   "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/icecream_"
>   "suffix": ".png" } } ] "verified": false "stats": { "tipCount": 15
>   "usersCount": 674 "checkinsCount": 561 "visitsCount": 1203 } "url":
>   "http://www.roselleto.com" "price": { "tier": 1 "message": "Cheap"
>   "currency": "$" } "likes": { "count": 45 "groups": [ { "type":
>   "others" "count": 45 "items": [ ] } ] "summary": "45 Likes" } "like":
>   false "dislike": false "ok": false "rating": 8.8 "ratingColor":
>   "73CF42" "ratingSignals": 54 "allowMenuUrlEdit": true "beenHere": {
>   "count": 0 "unconfirmedCount": 0 "marked": false
>   "lastCheckinExpiredAt": 0 } "specials": { "count": 0 "items": [ ] }
>   "photos": { "count": 39 "groups": [ { "type": "checkin" "name":
>   "Friends' check-in photos" "count": 0 "items": [ ] } { "type": "venue"
>   "name": "Venue photos" "count": 39 "items": [ "0": { "id":
>   "5d59a14744209c00089c596b" "createdAt": 1566155079 "source": { "name":
>   "Swarm for iOS" "url": "https://www.swarmapp.com"
>
> etc

Comment: Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication for details

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, a "?" instead of "&" is required after the venue_id

'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(VENUE_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION)

Refer to the Q&A below:

[Authentication error in nested API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747084/authentication-error-in-nested-api-request)